# jquery remove coming as part of richfaces

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, richfaces, jquery-1.3.2

I am using the 3.3.x version of richfaces and that contains the 1.3.2 jquery version.
and our system(other resources) found that jquery version 1.3.2 have security vulnerability.
I want to remove completly the jquery version and want to use later version 1.6.4 jquery.
If it possible than let me know how?
and If not than what should I do?
NOTE: I can't update the richfaces jar version :(

Comment: use atelast jquery version 2.X

Comment: any version is fine but my question is different... how we can replace the jquery

Answer (score 1):

Changing jQuery version was a task when I decided to add PrimeFaces to my Richfaces project. I don't know if it is posible in RF 3.3.X (it's really ancient), but in RF 4.X it's possible and quite simple.

Here are docs [5.4.3. Resource mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Advanced_features.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Advanced_features-Resource_mapping) and here is some small working [example](https://github.com/camra/Richfaces-Primefaces-Problem) (not mine!). In `static-resource-mappings.properties` you can use any jQuery you want:

```
jquery.js=jquery-alternative-version.js
```

but you have to make that this version is compatibile with RichFaces.

Let us know if it works also in RF 3.3.X.

Comment: As far as I can tell the resource management works quite differently in RF 3, so this is not going to work.

Comment: @Makhiel Well, you certainly have better knowledge than me ;-) So thank you for the comment. Even though, I'll leave my answer. It can be useful for someone who want to change jQuery version in RF 4.X.

Comment: With the latest (heavily outdated) v4.5.17.Final of RichFaces you need to use `org.richfaces\:jquery.js=jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js` – the key has changed.

Comment: ...or use `org.richfaces\:jquery.js=primefaces/jquery/jquery.js` to refer to PrimeFaces, if available too.