# Remove jquery.js reference coming as part of Richfaces 4.x

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

During a security scan it was found that jquery.js ( version 1.12.3 ) coming as part of Richfaces 4.x to our application is a vulnerability . So we had to mitigate that and try to resource map it so that a newer version of Jquery is used , and the vulnerability is mitigated.
Using resource mapping i am trying to point it to jquery 3.5.0.
This is the link which i followed for resource mapping : https://lukas.fryc.eu/blog/2012/02/re-routing-jsf-resource-requests-with.html

Followed everything that is mentioned in that link.
But even after all these steps , i could see in the security scan , that the jquery.js file which is being packaged is still the older version coming from richfaces.

This is the path which is still pointing to the jquery older version coming from richfaces in the vulnerability report :

app_name/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/jquery.js

Is there anything i missed out here ?? or any attention to detail missed out in the resource mapping?
Any help/suggestion is welcome!!

Comment: I don't use RichFaces but I doubt it works if you get this version loaded. You most likely also Need A compatibility Script but even with that I doubt It will work.

Comment: I could see a similar issue , where this was given as the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446597/jquery-remove-coming-as-part-of-richfaces   ... So based on this ... any suggestions ???

Comment: That was 1.3 to 1.6, you ask about 1.12 to 3.5... I doubt it is going to work... (and like mentioned, also search for compatibility libraries...  I doubt there is one for this)

Comment: Oh alright , thanks!!

Comment: 'which is being packaged' - what do you mean by that? Try to change version to 1.12.4 for a start. In my answer from the comment, you have full (working!) example from Github.

Comment: Hi Emil , what I mean by packaged is that it's coming as the older version (1.12.3) itself in the Richfaces-Core Jar which is part of our application.war file... Also an additional question in case you have more idea regarding jQuery , what kind impacts could be seen in the richfaces components , could it break existing functionalities of any components or rendering of components is impacted?? Just asking this so that we have prior knowledge regarding the impacts before investing efforts into this..

Comment: The old jQuery is always going to be in the jar file (and its presence is not a security issue). Is the jQuery that gets imported on your page the old version or not?

Comment: Hi , no we are not importing that old version of Jquery in our application. So as long as its just packaged and the jquery version is not used , it is not a security issue?